# Renaming Rows in gtsummary, tbl_regression/tbl_stack

Tags: rename, gtsummary

I am using gtsummary and have stacked tables for the outputs of 11 different models on top of one another using the tbl_regression and tbl_stack functions. I am looking to see how the odds ratios of one consistent independent variable change across different dependent variables of interest. When I print out the tbl_stack output, it gives me 11 repeated rows of the independent variable name of interest, instead of the name of the unique dependent variables I am interested in. Does anyone know how to rename rows in tbl_stack (either manually or automatically) to put the dependent variable names in the rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tbl_regression(label=)` argument to change the labels for the repeating variable to match the outcome for each model before you stack them.

There is, however, a shortcut using `tbl_uvregerssion()`.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> '1.3.6'

trial %>%
  select(response, death, age) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    x = age, 
    method = glm,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  ) %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Outcome**")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I used the label function to solve this (have covariates in my model). I have a follow up question that I've posted here that I would love your thoughts on!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673290/merging-tbl-svysummary-and-stacked-tbl-regression-tables-with-different-variable

Comment: If they are the same covariates, you can use `tbl_uvregression(..., formula = "{y} ~ {x} + bmi")` to adjust each model for BMI. Only the x covariate will be shown.

Comment: if the post answers your question, please do mark it as correct and upvote...it'll help others find it in the future. @GMJ

Comment: Done. My rep score is still too low to have my upvote show up. And I am using survey data though so tbl_uvregression doesn't work. Thanks though.