# Merging tbl_svysummary and stacked tbl_regression tables with different variable names but same labels

Tags: gtsummary

Follow up question to ([Renaming Rows in gtsummary, tbl_regression/tbl_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649545/renaming-rows-in-gtsummary-tbl-regression-tbl-stack/65649707#65649707)):

I am now trying to merge the renamed, stacked table (Table 1) with a tbl_summary table that includes the prevalence for each of the outcomes (Table 2). However, because each renamed line of Table 1 is, in reality, just the same variable repeated over and over again, it doesn't merge with Table 2, instead creating a (Table 3) that has duplicated outcome names stacked onto one another. Any way to merge these tables so that the lines of Table 1 match seamlessly with those from Table 2?

Comment: I don't follow 100% your scenario, but the variable names must match to merge tables with `tbl_merge()`.

Comment: Gotcha. So there is no way to merge tables based on labels instead of variable names? Aside from all the details I provided, I am just trying to match on the manual labels I provided instead of the variable names.

Comment: You can look into using `modify_table_body()`. It's an advanced-user function that requires some knowledge of the internals. A merge that merges just on label could be constructed somewhat easily. The code is the easier part...understanding the structures will be more of a hassle.

Comment: I think you'll find it easier to rename your variables to match, then use `tbl_merge()`

Comment: If you use the `tbl_uvregression()` function to construct your table, the variable names will match.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
As of gtsummary v 1.4.0, `tbl_uvregression()` now accepts survey objects.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

# convert trial data frame to survey object
tbl <- 
  survey::svydesign(
    data = trial[c("response", "death", "age", "marker")], 
    ids = ~1, 
    weights = ~1
  ) %>%
  # build univariate regression models
  tbl_uvregression(
    x = age, 
    method = survey::svyglm,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    formula = "{y} ~ {x} + marker",
    label = list(response = "Response", death = "Death"),
    hide_n = TRUE,
    include = -marker
  ) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  add_nevent() %>%
  modify_header(
    label = "**Outcome**",
    estimate = "**Age OR**"
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks as always for these responses, really grateful for your attention here. I unfortunately do not think this response works, however, because I am working with survey data and i do not think tbl_uvregression works here with the survey design and multiple covariates. Any thoughts? If I want to understand modify_table_body() and go that route, do you have any resources that you recommend? I've looked at the gtsummary site a bit but am still honestly confused about how to manipulate the internals freely. Thank you again for your thoughts.

Comment: The only resource on the internal structure is this vignette http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gtsummary_definition.html

Comment: Please feel free to open a GitHub Issue requesting survey support for tbl_uvregression. I don't think it'd be difficult to add in the future.

Comment: Thank you, will do! Also to be clear, with tbl_uvregression () can you add multiple covariates into the formula function i.e. ("{y} ~ {x} + marker + covariate 2 + covariate 3 + ...  + covariate 27")? If so, adding survey support would make this function exactly what I am looking for! If not, I will also submit a GitHub issue to request that functionality as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can add as many covariates as needed

Comment: Thanks! I see you added the github issue already, thanks for being so responsive and on top of it!

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you can test the update. 
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/pull/740